# DuplicateKeyException after deleting record in an other program

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a problem with C# and Linq. If I create a record, delete it in another program (while the C# program is still open), and want to re-create the record in C#, I am getting a DuplicateKeyException, although the table is physically empty. A refresh of the table did not help. I guess there is some index cache affected.

I am using MS SQL Server 2012.

**Step 1: Insert something into the table.**

```
  CUSTOMERS test2 = new CUSTOMERS();
  test2.CUSTOMERID = 10;
  test2.FOO = 1;
  test2.BAR = 1;
  CoreDB.CUSTOMERS.InsertOnSubmit(test2);
  CoreDB.SubmitChanges();
```

**Step 2: In a DIFFERENT program (e.g. SQL Explorer), remove the record.**

**Step 3: Refresh the table and check the number of records.**

```
CoreDB.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, CoreDB.CUSTOMERS);
if (CoreDB.CUSTOMERS.Count(ds=> ds.CUSTOMERID == 10 && ds.FOO == 1 && ds.BAR == 1) == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("Good! Record not available anymore"); // <-- will be shown
}
```

**Step 4: Try to insert the record again. It will fail.**

```
  CUSTOMERS test1 = new CUSTOMERS();
  test1.CUSTOMERID = 10;
  test1.FOO = 1;
  test1.BAR = 1;
  CoreDB.CUSTOMERS.InsertOnSubmit(test1);
  CoreDB.SubmitChanges(); // <-- DuplicateKeyException
```

It only works when I close the connection and re-open it. If I just refresh the table, the count will become 0, but there will be an index conflict, although the table is physically empty.

What can I do to make it work without always opening/closing the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried re-initializing your `DbContext` before doing any updates?

Start with **Step 1**

```
CoreDB = new YourContextHere(); //re-initialize context to clear memory changes
CUSTOMERS test2 = new CUSTOMERS();
test2.CUSTOMERID = 10;
test2.FOO = 1;
test2.BAR = 1;
CoreDB.CUSTOMERS.InsertOnSubmit(test2);
CoreDB.SubmitChanges();
```

Then do **Step 2** and **Step 3**

As for **Step 4**, do the same with step 1

```
CoreDB = new YourContextHere(); //re-initialize context to clear memory changes
CUSTOMERS test1 = new CUSTOMERS();
test1.CUSTOMERID = 10;
test1.FOO = 1;
test1.BAR = 1;
CoreDB.CUSTOMERS.InsertOnSubmit(test1);
CoreDB.SubmitChanges();
```

**SubmitChanges** does not rollback transactions/operations done in memory and is not tracked by your current db context (**CoreDB**), changes in memory will need to be rolled back manually within the context by re-initializing it every time you need to make changes to your database

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it. But I don't understand the thing with the transactions. Doesn't "SubmitChanges" actually commit the internal transaction? (Therefore, there is no "open" transaction, which needs to be either rolled back or committed?)

Comment: Yes, `SubmitChanges` will commit the internal transaction, but it will ONLY commit those done WITHIN the context, and not the ones outside of it (such as step 2). Since your context actually committed the transaction, the database context "saved" within your memory is the one without the actions from step 2. Ultimately you will need to refresh your context to recognize the changes done outside said context

Comment: That being said, there is no "open" transaction once you decide to call on `SubmitChanges`, but, the context will be saved for later re-use (the same exact context) unless you decide to re-initialize it